# Querying a list in a list efficently

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to query a list of products, and each product has a list of orders.

So something like this:

```
from s in products
join o in orders on s.ProductID = o.ProductID
select new ProductRecord
{
  ProductName = s.Name,
  OrderList = o.Select(x=>new OrderRecord(OrderID = x.OrderID, OrderName = x.OrderName).ToList()
}
```

OrderList is a `List<OrderRecord>`

My query is much more complicated than this, but this illustrates the idea.

In the end I want to list something like this out on my webpage:

```
Product 1
    Order 1
    Order 2
    Order 3

Product 2
    Order 4
    Order 5
    Order 6
```

This isn't working very well though.  It's a slow query and Mini Profiler says I have 100 duplicate queries on my page.  If I take out that `OrderList` stuff everything is snappy.

I think I'm approaching the problem all wrong.  How do I query this efficiently?

Comment: I think you will have duplicate products in you query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `ToList` from query. Also use group join to get orders of product:

```
var query = from s in context.Products
            join o in context.Orders on s.ProductID equals o.ProductID into g
            select new ProductRecord
            {
                  ProductName = s.Name,
                  OrderList = g.Select(x => new OrderRecord() 
                                            { 
                                                OrderID = x.OrderID, 
                                                OrderName = x.OrderName
                                            })
            };
```

OrderList should be `IEnumerable<OrderRecord>`. Here is what SQL Profiler shows to me for such query:

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project1].[OrderID] AS [OrderID]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent2].[OrderID] AS [OrderID], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[OrderID] IS NULL) 
         THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2]
    FROM  [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent2] 
         ON [Extent1].[ProductID] = [Extent2].[ProductID]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[ProductID] ASC, [Project1].[C2] ASC
```

Comment: Even with the IEnumerable and the removal of the .ToList() I still get the repeat queries.  It does a separate select for each product record.  Turning it to IEnumerable just delays the access of those items, but at access time it still selects.

Comment: @Nate I checked with profiler - there is only one query with LEFT OUTER JOIN. Have you added `join...into` to your query?

Comment: I think the disconnect is my (overly) complex query.  You've put me on the right track, I just have to keep removing stuff until i don't get the multi queries.  thanks :)

Comment: Okay, so I've narrowed it down to my .Take(25).  In LINQ pad I can run it with and without the take.  With the take, I get the repeated queries.  Ideas?

Comment: @Nate still not true - `Take(25)` just adds `SELECT TOP (25)` to LEFT OUTER JOIN query. Btw it's not good to change your initial question

Comment: Okay, I'll start a new one.  LINQ pad is telling me that I'm sending out 26 queries, so it's obviously something else in my complex query.  I'll do a new question with a more robust example.  Thanks for the help.